# How to programmatically skip protractor test?

Tags: angular, protractor, automated-tests

Can I somehow skip protractor testcases if some conditions are true/false? 
Tried to use

```
        pending('skipped');
        expect(true).toBe(true);
```

But it marks it as failed

**Update**
Find how to add testcase to "Pending"
on prepare

```
      var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;
  SpecReporter.prototype.specDone = function (spec) {
    this.metrics.stopSpec(spec);
    var pending = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < spec.failedExpectations.length; i++) {
      if ( spec.failedExpectations[i].message.toLowerCase().indexOf('pending') >= 0) pending = true;
    }
    if (spec.status === 'pending' || pending) {
      this.metrics.pendingSpecs++;
      this.display.pending(spec);
    } else if (spec.status === 'passed') {
      this.metrics.successfulSpecs++;
      this.display.successful(spec);
    } else if (spec.status === 'failed') {
      this.metrics.failedSpecs++;
      this.display.failed(spec);
    }
  };
```

And later on testcases you can use pending();

```
it(test some elements, function(){
 if(some conditions) {pending()}
} else {test elements}
```

And later you can manipulate your test report with tag pending.

Maybe not the best example, but it works for me now.

Comment: skipped test : 
 xit('will run', function(){
      expect(true).toBeTruthy();
});

Comment: Using `xit` would skip the whole `it` block instead of basing the check on the conditions wouldn't it.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best bet is to create a sequence that expects specific arguments, like:

```
export class Sequence {
  static performAfterCondition(conditionToMeet) {
    if (conditionToMeet){
       describe(`conditionTrueTests`, () => {
          it(`Test 1`, async () => {
            expect(await true).toBe(true);
          });

          it(`Test 2`, async () => {
            expect(await true).toBe(true);
          });
       });
    }else{
       describe(`conditionFalseTests`, () => {
          it(`Test 1`, async () => {
            expect(await false).toBe(false);
          });

          it(`Test 2`, async () => {
            expect(await false).toBe(false);
          });
       });
    }
  }
}
```

and call this within your spec file, like:

```
describe('calltests', () => {
        Sequence.performAfterCondition(condition);
});
```